# Firebase authentication after user had been deleted

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have an android application which uses Firebase Authentication via Facebook. A user can delete their account in the application using the following function:

```
override fun deleteUserAcc() {
    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    val userToken = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(authTokenProvider.provideToken())
    user?.reauthenticate(userToken)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        user.delete()
    }
}
```

After this a user really gets deleted on the Firebase servers. However when they try to access the application again and log in one more time, they are not able to do this (their account with uid had been deleted and somehow they are not assigned a new one uid).

The login function and the onSuccess callback are both implemented and called.

```
override fun login(): Completable {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
            activityReference.get(),
            listOf("public_profile", "user_birthday", "user_location")
    )
    return CompletableSubject.create().apply {
        loginSubject = this
    }
}


override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
    val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(result.accessToken.token)
    authTokenProvider.saveToken(result.accessToken.token)
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    getInfoOnFirestore(loginSubject)
                } else {
                    loginSubject.onError(task.exception!!)
                }
            }
}
```

What can possibly be the cause of the following issue?

Comment: I provided a little more info to the question. That is the issue. It's already done using LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(...) to authenticate by facebook and implementing the onSuccess(...) and onCancel() callbacks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have a similar issue where the user can delete their Firebase Auth login, but not their facebook login manager credentials.

Comment: Unfortunately no, didn't manage to find a way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I fixed my issue by updating all pods. I'm sure you tried that already though..

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but I know what the issue is. Firebase deletes only the authentication, which means that the real-time database is still there with the same uid. In order to delete the database entry as well, you need to upgrade to the blaze program and add the extension.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to verify whether this is the solution, as that project is long gone. But thanks for your input, hope it can help someone else